# Shortest way of finding the number of incongruent roots modulo 13 of $x^2+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the number of incongruent roots modulo $13$ of $x^2+1$.
I tried using complete residue system. But I want use a method that is less tedious than CRS.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think the shortest way is to compute $x^2+1 \pmod {13}$ in a spreadsheet for $0 \le x \le 12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are two $x$ for $p$ where $x^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$. These $x$ are $(\frac {p-1}{2})!$ and $-(\frac {p-1}{2})!$, which can be proved with Wilson`s Theorem. That is, if such $x$ exists.

For such $x$ to exist, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ .